# Ignore multiple specific files with svn

Tags: svn

Our build system generates a number of files that are scattered around the source tree.

These files the show up when running `svn status`

In the example below all of the files with a '?' in the `thirdparty` directory have been generated by the build system.

e.g.

```
svn status
M       common/db/unit_test/src/db_payload_builder_test_suite.cpp
?       common/db/unit_test/Makefile
M       common/lib/osal/variant/linux/public_inc/osal_specific_msgq.hpp
M       common/lib/enb/public_inc/enb_service.h
?       thirdparty/lib/curl/public_inc_arm
?       thirdparty/lib/curl/public_inc_x86
?       thirdparty/lib/curl/originals/config.log
?       thirdparty/lib/curl/originals/libcurl.pc
?       thirdparty/lib/curl/originals/config.status
?       thirdparty/lib/curl/originals/libtool
?       thirdparty/lib/curl/originals/curl-config
?       thirdparty/lib/curl/originals/src/curl
```

I would like to tell `svn` to ignore these files. I cannot simply specify directories that should be ignored since many of these directories contain sources that are checked in to the repository.

The example above is a subset of the files that are generated, we cannot use an ignore pattern because some of the generated files match files that we do not wish to ignore (e.g. xxx_.h" )

I have tried using `svn propset svn:ignore 'somefile' dir` but I can only manage to tell svn to ignore one specific file per directory.

How can I specify multiple specific files for svn to ignore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass it a list of files to ignore, one per line

```
vnix$ svn propset svn:ignore 'config.log
> libcurl.pc
> config.status
> libtool
> curl-config' thirdparty/lib/curl/originals
```

... where `vnix$` is your shell's primary prompt and `>` is the secondary prompt.

Don't look scared, that's how you write multi-line strings in the shell.

Alternatively, feed it a file on stdin:

```
vnix$ svn propset svn:ignore -F - thirdparty/lib/curl/originals <<HERE
> config.log
> libcurl.pc
> config.status
> libtool
> curl-config
> HERE
```

See also the [Red Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html), although the example is not very explicit for your particular scenario.

Comment: Thanks - that works a treat. Is there a way to add additional files to the ignore list or would I need to include files tat are already ignored if I modify the 'svn:ignore' property for a directory

Comment: You can use 'propedit' instead of 'propset' but it's interactive, i.e. not very easily scriptable (though it's not terribly hard, either).

Answer (score 9):

One line solution:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "file1"$'\n'"file2"$'\n'"file3" .
```

Answer (score 3):

If you starting to read docs, you'll discover, that

- svn:ignore can be applied to folder, which contain have-to-be-ignored files, not only to parent of this folder
- svn:ignore define pattern of files, which be ignored in future `svn add` and `svn status` by default, but **only for unversioned files**. Files already under version control **doesn't affected by svn:ignore**

Your forkflow have to be:

1. Add all needed files in SVN
2. For folders, which are targets of your builder, add *.* ignore-pattern
3. Test patterns and completeness of blocking by test-run of build and checking output of `svn st` in the root of WC

Comment: We already have a number of test patterns set up, unfortunately the build of some thirdparty libraries generates files that match patterns that we do not want to ignore. Since we are still creating new files and components adding an ignore pattern that matches all of the auto-generated files could be dangerous