# svn:ignore propedit append rule

Tags: bash, svn, vim

## Append Problem

I am trying to read rules from a file and in a bash script set the rules, for this to work I need to append the svn:ignore rules to the directory.

I have an example set of data:

```
/js/blank.html
/js/index.php
/js/spacer.gif
```

If I try to run `svn propedit svn:ignore js/ < "blank.html"` or `echo "test" | svn propedit svn:ignore js/` I get the following error:

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
svn: E200012: system('/usr/bin/editor svn-prop.tmp') returned 256
```

Is it possible to append rules to svn:ignore?

## Alternatives

I know you can use propset to set a list of rules, one per line as per [Ignore multiple specific files with svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865354/ignore-multiple-specific-files-with-svn) but that is not the behaviour I am looking for as I would have to order my list in bash some how and make sure I do not overwrite any  existing changes.

Interestingly this came up in [2005 but there was no outcome](http://marc.info/?t=110749423200002&r=1&w=2), maybe I should track him down.

If anyone knows how to use propset to append that would be useful too.

Thanks

## proplist

I am automating these additions from a file, so I want to ignore all of these apart from `local.xml.sample`

```
ls -h errors/
404.php  default     enterprise        processor.php
503.php  design.xml  local.xml.sample  report.php
```

My propedit rules:

```
.htaccess
404.php
503.php
design.php
processor.php
report.php
design.xml
```

Proplist output:

```
svn proplist errors
Properties on 'errors':
  svn:ignore
```

There are more complex examples I can give, but the baseline is that I am trying to automate all rules from a single file to create a reliable way of ignore all core files of a software package from my repository. I know I am using the wrong tool for the job, but management is management, I feel like I am hitting a nail with a piece of paper.

Comment: Why do you insist on using `propedit` and Vim? Can you add the output of `proplist` before and after so that we get a clearer picture of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am happy to use `propset` but there is no `--append` option. Will add proplist output doesn't show me rules applied though.

Comment: Good question. Shame nobody gave an answer.